# Setting labels for image automatically

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have a 2D array, and I plot in into three lines in one image, each line represents the numbers in each column.

I would like to set their labels as 'column = 1', 'column = 2', 'column = 3' automatically, based on which column the line represent.

How can I achieve this?

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    [1, 2, 4],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [5, 7, 9]
]

arr = np.array(data)

#Plotting

arr = arr[:,0:3]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 3)
x = np.asarray(x)

plt.plot(x, arr, label="column")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the lables in the `legend` method,

```
...
lines = plt.plot(x, arr)
column_names = tuple("column_" + str(i+1) for i,x in enumerate(data))
plt.legend(lines, column_names, bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```